# How to store a list of points in an XML file

Tags: xml

Hello :) I'm beginning with xml and I am writing a simple xml file. 
My question is pretty simple : is there a way to store a list of double into this xml file ?
I can't really think of an efficient way :/

Thank you for your answers or guidance :)

Here is a sample of my code :

```
`<state>
    <name>Name state 2</name>
    <x>x</x>
    <y>y</y>
    <width>w</width>
    <height>h</height>
    <nlinks>2</nlinks>
    <effect>1</effect>
    <signal>
        <name>Signal 1</name>
        <amplitude>3</amplitude> <!--parameter 3 -->
        <duration>10</duration>  <!--input 0 -->
        <listOfPoints>...</listOfPoints>
    </signal>
</state>`
```

Comment: Do you mean you want a list inside your `listOfPoints`? 'cause I can't really figure out what " a list of double" means..

Comment: Exactly :)
So far, I am thinking of using a string. For example <listOfPoints>"{0, 1, 10, 1, 0}"</listOfPoints>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML works like a tree,
So if you want a list inside one of your nodes, just expand that:

```
<state>
    <name>Name state 2</name>
    <x>x</x>
    <y>y</y>
    <width>w</width>
    <height>h</height>
    <nlinks>2</nlinks>
    <effect>1</effect>
    <signal>
        <name>Signal 1</name>
        <amplitude>3</amplitude> <!--parameter 3 -->
        <duration>10</duration>  <!--input 0 -->
        <listOfPoints>
             <point>0</point>
             <point>1</point>
             <point>10</point>
             <point>0</point>
        </listOfPoints>
    </signal>
</state>
```

See [W3School Xml Tree](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_tree.asp) or
See [Sitepoint tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/really-good-introduction-xml/) for some more info about making up XML.

Comment: So there is no other alternative ? I mean, if I have 100 points, I'll have to expand each of the 100 ?

Comment: That's XML.. used for big sets of data. Not used to be read, but for processing in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

**It would be helpful:-**

```
<marker>
<pose x="0" y="-1.3" theta="1.57" />
<geometry>
    <point x="0" y="0" />
    <point x="0" y="0.3" />
    <point x="0.3" y="0.3" />
    <point x="0.3" y="0" />
</geometry>
</marker>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a schema, XML only has strings: it's up to the application to decide whether the strings represent doubles.

If you define the types with a schema, there are two possible representations: you can use a whitespace-separated list (either in an attribute value or in text content):

```
<points>1.2 1.5 1.6 -3.7</points>
```

or you can use a sequence of child elements:

```
<points>
  <point>1.2</point>
  <point>1.5</point>
  <point>1.6</point>
  <point>1.7</point>
</points>
```

To advise you which representation is "better", we would need to know more about your project requirements; but both these forms are to be found in popular and carefully-thought out XML vocabularies.